# How do I get triple click to work in Visual Studio's Text Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Go into Notepad, Internet Explorer or most other applications that display or edit text. Triple click on some text. Windows will select the entire paragraph under the cursor.

This doesn't work in Visual Studio 2005.

How do I get triple click support in the Visual Studio text editor?

do VS 2008 or VS 2010 solve this?

Is there a macro, setting or plugin that will solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it, but CodeProject has an article on [SmartHelp 3.04](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/smarthelp.aspx?fid=4397&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=244843) which mentions that you can triple click to select a whole line.

Also, from [Craig Shoemaker's blog](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/craig_shoemaker/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010-enhancements.aspx).

About VS 2010.

> Further enhancements include the
>   ability to triple-click an expansive
>   element like a table and the editor
>   selects the entire table’s markup.
>   Want to surround that table with some
>   additional markup? Just start typing
>   with the table selected and your
>   markup is inserted around the selected
>   code.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an extension for this for Visual Studio 2010 that you can [download from the VS Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/2bbdc70c-32f7-4b69-8cff-d8190cae0cc7) or directly from the extension manager in Visual Studio, by searching for "triple click" or my name.

You can also read [the blog post I wrote about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/noahric/archive/2009/10/19/beta-2.aspx) and check out [the source, on github](http://github.com/NoahRic/tripleclick).